# DevExtreme: DataGrid, Popup Editing, Form customization

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datagrid, asp.net-core-mvc, devextreme

I have a datagrid as follows.

**Problem 1:** DataGrid has `"Address"` field. This field should be `TextArea`. When I added to `[editorType: "dxTextArea"]` property, also filter row is changing as `TextArea`, I dont want that. Address just should be in form as `TextArea` not in filter rows too.

I did that to solve this problem (for me): Removed the `[editorType: "dxTextArea"]` and added the `[formItem > template]` that solved my problem but another problem is here now update is not working now.

Here is my sample: https://codepen.io/mstfcck/pen/vbVaVx?editors=0010

```
        {
            dataField: "Address",
            formItem: {
                colSpan: 1,
                template: function (data, itemElement) {
                    itemElement.append("<div id='textAreaContainer'>")
                        .dxTextArea({
                            value: data.component.option('formData')[data.dataField],
                            onValueChanged: function (e) {
                                data.component.updateData(data.dataField, e.value);
                            }
                        });
                },
                editorOptions: {
                }
            }              
        }
```

data.component.option('formData')[data.dataField] is not working. I cant get the current data of Address field. I could not find a solution for that.

**Problem 2:** colSpan is not working. My client wants to see that form just one column. As you can see in this form has 2 column.

My references are:

- Popup Editing:
  https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/DataGrid/PopupEditing/jQuery/Light/
- formItem:
  https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/17_2/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxDataGrid/Configuration/columns/#formItem
- colSpan:
  https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/17_2/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxForm/Item_Types/SimpleItem/#colSpan
- template:
  https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/17_2/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxForm/Item_Types/SimpleItem/#template
- template sample:
  https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/17_2/Guide/Widgets/Form/Configure_Simple_Items/#Customize_a_Simple_Item
- Form Customized Item:
  https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/Form/CustomizeItem/jQuery/Light/

Comment: Use colspan outside the **formItem:** after **dataField**

Comment: @TAB already tried. Didn't work.

Comment: For Problem 2 i.e. colspan issue:

have you tried to use bootstrap classes inside 

    <div class='container-fluid'>
      <div class="row justify-content-between">
          <div class="col-md-12">
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>

Comment: This is a work around solution. Haven't tried but I want to know that how to solve with configs.